# What Should I do About An Answer I Can't Verify

Tags: discussion, answers, answering-questions

Several months ago I asked a question on [server fault](https://serverfault.com/q/97020/10975).  Someone just answered it but we replaced our 10.4 deployment with a 10.5 deployment earlier this year and I now have no way to verify the solution.  What should I do?  I could just blindly accept the answer but I don't feel right about that but I also don't want the correct answer to be lost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can't verify it, i upvote it if you think it's helpful but don't mark is as the answer for the question.

Comment: +1 If you can't verify, and there's no way for you to be reasonably sure it's correct, don't mark it accepted. It's better to "languish unanswered" than to be potentially incorrect/misleading.